# List files whose name begin with any of the characters between a to k

Tags: files

How to list the files whose name begin with any of the character a to k (both inclusive)?

Comment: Do you want those files in the current dir or anywhere?

Comment: What are the characters `a` to `k`? Is `ḱ` one of them for instance?

Answer (score 6):

```
find . -type f -name '[a-k]*'
```

or (to be safe against locale problems)

```
find . -type f -name '[abcdefghijk]*'
```

Comment: *locale problems*, can you please provide an example? Are there locales where `[a-k] != [abcdefghijk]`?

Comment: @A.L See Stephane's comment on Ketan's answer

Comment: I'll admit I'm fuzzy on this - but doesn't this match less than `[a-k]` where locale might be a problem? I thought the locale thing was about it not getting collation weights quite right - like outliers that didn't fit. Maybe `LC_ALL=C find ...`?

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, the enumeration matches less than `[a-k]` (or equal to). `LC_ALL=C` is another way to solve that but it may cause problems if the `find` call needs non-C chars elsewhere: `find . -type f -name '[abcdefghijk]*' -printf "übereinstimmende Datei: %p\n"`

Comment: Interesting... I guess in that case `... -exec sh -c 'LC_ALL=..; printf ...'` and so on might apply but it definitely gets more complicated. Anyway, thanks, and good answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -name "[a-k]*"
```

Comment: In most locales (including modern US ones), that includes `á` (or `æ` or `ǳ`) for instance but not `ḱ` (also note that nothing guarantees that file names are encoded in the same charset as that of the user's locale).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Very interesting, thanks! So, yeah, Hauke Laging's answer is more complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bash command line [expansion feature](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) for this.

```
$ ls -l [a-k]*
```

`[a-k]` refers to alphabets from `a` to `k`.
`*` refers to any character any number of times.

So now bash looks for files starting with letter `a` to `k` and followed by any character any number of times.

Comment: If some of those files are of type _directory_, `ls` will list their content. You may want to add the `-d` option like similar answers. Note that what `[a-k]` actually means depends on the user's locale (it's generally _not_ `abcdefghijk` even in US locales nowadays)

Answer (score 2):

For the current directory only you can use

```
ls -d [a-k]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use shell globbing (test: `echo [a-k]*`). You usually need to iterate over files, so the usual pattern is `for file in [a-k]*; do something; done`. Never use `ls` for iteration.

Helpful read:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Better [not use `echo` for arbitrary data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) either.

Comment: +1 to stephane. You want to : `for file in [abcdefghijk]*; do something_with "$file" ; done` . Don't use echo/ls/find/etc. (I believe that's what Orion means, but the first sentence is misleading, I think... it *seems* to say "use echo [a-k]* instead of ls" (but the rest of the paragraph shows you know it's best to just use the glob directly) (so +1 for you in the end, too)

Comment: Sure, if you need iteration, you use `for`. `echo` was just for demonstration purposes, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

-To Be more specific since it was not clear whether it was to display the current directory files or system files, you can use one of the defined modes.

ls -d [a-k]*  -> to display the files/directories of the current place/directory/folder only.

or

find / -type f -name '[k]'* -> to display the files/whole system directories and by remembering that the difference here would be that the hidden items are not displayed, as with so already shown.

```
    find . -type f -name '[a-k]*'
```

if used the 'ls' command to also view the hidden use of this mode.

```
    ls -da [a-k]*
```

Comment: Hidden files are those whose name starts with `.` (which usually doesn't sit between `a` and `k`). `find . -name '[a-k]*'` will generally not list hidden files as a result, but it will still list files in hidden directories. `-a` for `ls` doesn't make a difference, it's the shell that builds the file list to pass to `ls`, `ls` only displays them. You might as well have used `printf '%s\n' [a-k]*`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, with zsh:
(And not getting into the ls/echo/etc. thread)

Display plain files in current directory:

```
ls [a-k]*(.)
```

Display all types of files in current directory:

```
ls -d [a-k]*
```

The same recursively:

```
ls -d -- **/[a-k]*(.)
```

(Not looking inside hidden directories) and

```
ls -d -- **/[a-k]*
```